# ServiceStack server on dynamic IP address desktop

Tags: servicestack, netsh

I am writing an application for deployment on desktop computers and using ServiceStack to expose json services to a central application which will consume them.  I'm using ServiceStack self hosting and I've pretty much just followed along with the ServiceStack wiki examples to get basic connectivity up and running.

This is used to start the server and bind it

```
appHost.Init();
appHost.Start("http://server_ip:port/");
```

Windows also needs to be configured so a non administrator can accept incoming requests; with this command from an administrator command prompt

```
netsh http add urlacl=http://server_ip:port/ user=desktopMachineName\desktopUserName listen=yes
```

note: this seems to be fragile.  If the urlBase in the appHost.Start(urlBase) command is different to the urlacl parameter in the netsh command then connections are refused by Windows.  btw I've only tried this with Windows 8.

Is there an alternate approach so that the application can withstand changes to the desktop computers ip address (e.g. caused by DHCP)?

This is a desktop environment so I don't expect users to have hostnames setup or static ip addresses for their computers.  I'm also trying to not require them to type in commands at a command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

It kinda depends on how the central application locates the apps on the desktop computers.

If you only have a list of static IP addresses, you will need the desktops to have static IP addresses.

If somehow your central app knows what the current IP address is (or maybe this is in a network and you can use the machine's name) then try `urlacl=http://+:port`.

This basically sets a wild card saying that anything coming in on this port via `http` goes to this app.

Then `apphost.Start("http://locahost:port/")` should work.